# Show all rows on PHP/sql

Tags: php, html, sql, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli

I'm doing a small app. The thing is that when I'm running it, it will only show 300 rows when I should have around 2000 that I inserted for the test. It just doesn't shows them. It shows 312 rows, and not the rest.

Here is the code:

```
    <!-- page content -->
        <div class="right_col" role="main">

            <div class="page-title">
                <div class="title_left">
                    <h3>Raw Inventory</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="title_right">
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 form-group pull-right top_search">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
                    </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="x_panel">
                        <div class="x_title">
                            <h2>Assets List</h2>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                                <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x_content">
                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="page-header clearfix">
                                                <h2 class="pull-left"></h2>
                                                <a href="create.php" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Add a new Asset</a>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php
                                            // Include config file
                                            require_once 'config.php';

                                            // Attempt select query execution
                                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_assets";
                                            if($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
                                                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                                                    echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
                                                    echo "<thead>";
                                                    echo "<tr>";
                                                    echo "<th>Asset</th>";
                                                    echo "<th>Model</th>";
                                                    echo "<th>Status</th>";
                                                    echo "<th>Location</th>";
                                                    echo "<th>Action</th>";

                                                    echo "</tr>";
                                                    echo "</thead>";
                                                    echo "<tbody>";
                                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                                        echo "<tr>";
                                                        echo "<td>" . ucfirst ($row['a_asset']) . "</td>";
                                                        echo "<td>" . $row['a_model'] . "</td>";
                                                        echo "<td>" . ucfirst($row['a_status']) . "</td>";
                                                        echo "<td>" . ucfirst($row['a_location']) . "</td>";
                                                        echo "<td>";
                                                        echo "<a href='read.php?id=". $row['a_asset'] ."' title='View Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span></a>  ";
                                                        echo "<a href='update.php?id=". $row['a_asset'] ."' title='Update Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>  ";
                                                        echo "<a href='delete.php?id=". $row['a_asset'] ."' title='Delete Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>";
                                                        echo "</td>";
                                                        echo "</tr>";
                                                    }
                                                    echo "</tbody>";
                                                    echo "</table>";
                                                    // Free result set
                                                    mysqli_free_result($result);
                                                } else{
                                                    echo "<p class='lead'><em>No records were found.</em></p>";
                                                }
                                            } else{
                                                echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($db);
                                            }

                                            // Close connection
                                            mysqli_close($db);
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
</body>
</html>                  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any idea what I can do about this?

This is really my only problem, and I just need to add more text right now.

Or well, if you guys want to give me tips to make a global search function that would also be nice. Like, being able to search for information on all columns. Though I'm quite sure that It's not that hard.

I wonder... I need to investigate how to sort the results by name or creation date too.

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: More details would be helpful. Is your page just crashing and not loading the rest, or does the page complete its process without showing the rest of the data?

Comment: It just doesn't shows it. It shows exactly 312 rows, and not more. It /does/ work.

Comment: If you can run the same query in mysql itself and get the 2000 rows, then I would suspect its a rendering issue, or your trying to load too much data on a single page. it could be any number of things from a limit on load time, a limit on page size, or similar settings. Do you HAVE to load all 2000 rows on the page? Or could you do like most places do and show the first 100-200  records, and then have a next button to show the next 201-300

Comment: I literally just added another 1000 entries and it shows 608 lines now. Still, not what there should be.

Comment: I don't really have to, but I really wanted to add a raw list for all the data. I guess I will need to just keep from 100 to 100 and get a search function then? Oh well. Time to google how to do that!

Comment: Yeah. Just truncated the table, and added 1000 entries. This time it only shows 280. Something weird is happening. Huh. Cleared cache, and reloaded. It shows 901 entries now.

Comment: Depending on the server, the browsers, the timeouts, and many other factors its pretty difficult to show large amounts of data in a single page. Its always better to show limited results, that either allows you to search, using *like* in mysql, or just let you hit next 100 results. Its rough on a web server and the browser to load a ton of data at once. If you plan to have more than a couple people using the database, it could cause some pretty hard performance issues.